# password not updating in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, edit

i create a page that allows the user to change his password but the update query is not working

the password_cotroller:

```
before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
  def edit
    
  end

  def update
    puts "Params: #{password_params.inspect}"
     if current_user.update_with_password(password_params)
        redirect_to profile_path, notice: "Password updated successfully."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Password not updated successfully."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

the page that contains the form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user, url: user_password_path, html: { method: :put,class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

                    
                                <div class="form-group mb-3  col-sm-15">
                                  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                                  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> character in minimum)</em>
                                  <% end %><br />
                                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control border-0 shadow-sm px-4 text-primary", placeholder: "password",type: "password" %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mb-3  col-sm-15">
                                
                                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control  border-0 shadow-sm px-4 text-primary", placeholder: "password confirmation",type: "password" %>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" style="background-color: #7db942;color:white;" class="btn btn-block text-uppercase mb-2 rounded-pill shadow-sm">Change password</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End -->

            </div>
```

I tried working with put and patch methods but same problem

and this what I have in my terminal:

```
Started PATCH "/users/password" for ::1 at 2023-04-24 23:46:04 +0100
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3IZjkoOc0bZXOcdy79rHAGZ6aFXI2GqXhL5gKtRH8tRx0/a8LqEoDCCz8LWU23+83EobHJi1kWr/ysFlzhvrXg==", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Params: <ActionController::Parameters {"password"=>"rahma", "password_confirmation"=>"rahma"} permitted: true>
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 8 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendering users/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/passwords/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_upper_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 281ms (Views: 14.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

this is my first project using ruby so I can't figure it out

Comment: You will note that there is no class name for the parameters, so they are not getting picked by the password_params method. Your form tag is incorrect. Need to change form_for(:user, url: user_password_path(current_user)...

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of the [`update_with_password`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FModels%2FDatabaseAuthenticatable:update_with_password)  method:

> `#update_with_password(params, *options) ⇒ Object`
>
> Update record attributes when `:current_password` matches, otherwise returns error on `:current_password`.
>
> This method also rejects the password field if it is blank (allowing users to change relevant information like the e-mail without changing their password). In case the password field is rejected, the confirmation is also rejected as long as it is also blank.

That means to use this method, you do not only need to pass the new `password`  and `password_confirmation` but also the user needs to confirm their `current_password` to authorize the password change.

To fix your issue, add another `password_field` to your form, named `current_password`. And add `:current_password` to the `password_params` in your controller.